# Analytic Solution to Generalized Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation, initial-value-problems

Is this type of PDE known to have a closed form solution?
$$
\partial_t(t,x) f = a \Delta f(t,x)\qquad f(0,x)=e^{bx};
$$
where $a,b>0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$?

If so, what is that solution and what is the name of this PDE?

Comment: Did you mean to use the Laplacian? $\nabla$ is generally used for the gradient. Moreover, if $a$ is an arbitrary function, then no, your problem does not have a "nice" closed form, for some reasonable definition of nice.

Comment: But a is smooth and bounded and not "totally arbitrary".

Comment: I simplified the problem so that Green's function methods may be used.  Still, given the very simply structure, I'm wondering if there's a closed-form solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [the Green's function method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Fundamental_solutions), the solution to your initial value problem is given by the following convolution
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi at}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4at}\right)g(y)\,dy;
$$
where in your case, $g(y)=e^{c+bx}$.  In this case, your integral is precisely the Laplace transform of a Gaussian density with mean $x$ and variance $2\sqrt{at}$.  This integral is well-known, and is called [the moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moment_and_cumulant_generating_functions) of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (with reparameterized with $\lambda =-b$; where $\lambda$ is the input variable of the Laplace transform).

Standard computations then show that 
$$
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t)=&e^{c+xb+\frac1{2} 4at b^2}\\=&
e^{c+xb+2at b^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I think you're missing a $b$ in the final solution

Comment: Looks about right now I believe :)

Comment: Nice. It might be worthwhile to mention that this solution is not necessarily unique given OP's stated conditions (adding a growth condition fixes the uniqueness problem). Also, it might be interesting to mention the connection to an expectation involving Brownian motion.

Comment: I thought the BM would be interesting but maybe not the OP's background.  But feel free to add the growth condition in a link; It's been a while since I did that kinda thing.   :)